# DocuSign API - JWT token generation API nodejs

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm having trouble generating toke access with jwt docusign documentation is very confusing. Does anyone have an example in nodejs.

I already got an example in the directory but it's presented a lot of error.

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node

Does anyone have an example I can follow?

Comment: what error do you get?